# Gridlines in Export from radGrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I am exporting to Excel using a radGrid. When I export the gridlines in Excel are turned off and I have to go in manually and turn them on. Is there a way to enable the gridlines in Excel when you export the file from radGrid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-html-export.html) is a sample up on Telerik's site.

There are a few sections which describe different formatting techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the GridLines property to Both.
This helped me to show gridlines in Excel.

Comment: <rad:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"  GridLines="Both" >

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)